# Change {NULL} in Postgres ARRAY to NULL

Tags: arrays, postgresql, null

I have table `t` with an array column `z` in Postgres 9.5. I want to select `id` where `z` is either `NULL` OR `{NULL}`.

```
id |   z
---+--------
 1 | {NULL} 
 2 |  null
```

See [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=af759ff36cff88bc92badad38b8dd783)

I tried changing `{NULL}` to `NULL` with `array_remove()`:

```
SELECT id, 
array_remove(z,NULL) as removed
from t;
```

Returns:

```
id |    z   | removed 
---+--------+-------
 1 | {NULL} |   {}      
 2 |  null  |  null
```

However, if I query this:

```
select id, z from t where removed is null;
```

I still get id 1. Ideally, I'd like to avoid unnesting and grouping back up.

Comment: Please provide table definition. [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=ed10f79312677e6a442a63c47ae7e621)

Comment: The question is misleading, it would be good if you could make it clearer. If I understand the title well, you need `nullif(z, '{null}')`

Comment: I edited the question as best I could and added a dbfiddle (demo)[https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=af759ff36cff88bc92badad38b8dd783]

Comment: It's still not clear, what you are trying  to achieve: The table definition in your fiddle has an integer field z. You write _"where z is either null OR {NULL}"_ but z can't be `{NULL}` given your table definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To ***replace an array with a single NULL element (`'{NULL}'`) with `NULL`***, I suggest [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF):

```
SELECT id, NULLIF(z, '{NULL}') AS z
FROM   t;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=fd444f4cac91a9d19ca121de637c719c)*

`'{NULL}'` is an (untyped) [array literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT) and the same value as resulting from  `ARRAY[NULL]` - which defaults to data type `text[]` without explicit input type or casting.  The above works for *any* array type: `int[]`, `date[]`, ... because the literal is coerced to the type of `z` implicitly.

An empty array (`'{}'`) or an array with 1 or more NULL elements (`'{NULL}'`) are not the same as `NULL`, `array_remove()` is not the right tool.

Comment: Correct link for [array literal](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT)

Comment: @Constantine: While my link wasn't wrong, yours is better. I updated accordingly, thanks.